# How to Import Existing Keys on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

In my System C: blackberry eclipse ganymede has been installed. in D: blackberry eclipse galileo has been installed. i'm working on galileo version. Now i installed bb java blugin 1.3.0 (helios) on C:.

I get 3 files (sigtool.csk, sigtool.db, sigtool.set) from 
     D:\BB_Eclipse_Galileo\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.29\components\bin  and save the three files on another location.

i import existing key in helilos, i navigate to the saved path. it successfully completed.

When i signin in helilos, its throws"Unable to perform code signing operation for the client because they have no signing attempts left."

But when i check on galileo. its successfully signin.

Pls help which files have to import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the article [Backup and Restore BlackBerry Code Signing Keys](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Backup-and-Restore-BlackBerry-Code-Signing-Keys/ta-p/837925).

Comment: i get the file and stored as noted on the link. But still i can't signin in new eclipse.

Comment: Sorry, that process worked perfectly for me.  You might have to reach out to devsupport@rim.com for further assistance.